# Consider a random variable $X$ with the log-normal pdf $f(x) ={1\over \sqrt{2π}}x^{−1}exp^{{−0.5 (logx)^2}}$, $x>0$.

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, means

Consider a random variable $X$ with the log-normal pdf $f(x) ={1\over \sqrt{2π}}x^{−1}exp^{{−0.5 (logx)^2}}$, $x>0$.

a) Find the mean and the variance of $X$.

I know that $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx=1$, but this says "consider the random variable $X$ with the log-normal pdf" so would I actually be integrating $\int_0^\infty x f(x) dx$ for the mean? The reason I ask (and I'm skeptical) is because the solution to that integral is disgusting and has $i$ in the solution and that doesn't seem to be applicable for what I'm doing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See here for some approaches for the mean: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409702/expected-value-of-a-lognormal-distribution

Comment: Disgusting?!? :)

Answer (score 0):

hint: it is $\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)\, dx$. To evaluate this make the substitution $y=\log\, x$. And then use the following: $-\frac 12 y^{2}+y=-\frac 1 2 (y-1)^{2} +\frac 1 2$. You should get the answer as $\sqrt e$. [ You have to use the fact $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac 1 2 y^{2}}\, dy =1$]

Comment: Should the substitution be $y=\log x$?

Comment: @ddswsd Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: If I let $y= \log x$, then the integral becomes ${1\over \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty} ^{\infty} e^{-0.5y^{2}+y} dy$. I don't think that equals $\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: @ddswsd The integral you have written is $\sqrt e$ as far as I can see. Can you show me how you evaluated it?

Comment: Interesting...I put that integral into wolfram alpha and used -0.5 and 0.5 instead of writing them as fractions and the answer they gave wasn't $\sqrt{e}$. Then I changed the decimals to fractions and the answer is $\sqrt{e}$. I see why you chose to complete the square. Really clever! Thank you!

Comment: Where can I find the derivation of that integral? The textbook I use just states that it equals $1$. I want to be able to understand the derivation.

Comment: $(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/2}\, dx)^{2} =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/2}\, dx\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}/2}\, dy=\int_{\mathbb R^{2}} e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})/2}\, dxdy$. Use polar coordinates to evaluate this. You will get $2\pi$.